# how to save file in txt format in javascript but only specific part/specific element tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Hey all i want to save txt format a particular data shown on page.

Variables You Entered:

People you are going to teach:a

1 Result They Really Want:b

2 Result They Really Want:c

1 Thing They FEAR Most: d

2 Thing They FEAR Most:e

Time frame You Can Deliver in:f

I'm going to teach a how to b

I'm going to teach a how to b in c

I'm going to teach a how to c

Please do help me out with this thanks a lot.

```js
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
function myFunction() {

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 document.getElementById("but1").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but2").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but3").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but4").style.display = "block";


 var a = document.getElementById("myText1").value;

    var b = document.getElementById("myText2").value;

    var c = document.getElementById("myText3").value;

    var d = document.getElementById("myText4").value;

    var e = document.getElementById("myText5").value;

    var f = document.getElementById("myText6").value;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var col = "Variables You Entered:";

  var one = "lorem1:" + a;
  var two = "#lorem2:" + b;
  var three = "#2lorem3:" + c; 
  var four = "#1 lorem4: " + d;
  var five = "#2 lorem5:" + e;
  var six = "lorem6:" + f;

  document.getElementById("col").innerHTML = col;

  //var onetext = one.concat(a);

  document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = one;
  document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = two;
  document.getElementById("three").innerHTML = three;
  document.getElementById("four").innerHTML = four;


     var str1 = "test ";

     var str2 = " test1 ";

     var str3 = " test2 ";

     var str4 = " test3 ";

     var str5 = " test4";

     var str6 = " test5 ";


     var res1 = str1.concat(a,str2,b);

     document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = res1;

     var res2 = str1.concat(a,str2,b,str3,c);

     document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = res2;

     ////////////////////////////////

     var res3 = str1.concat(a,str2,c);

     document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = res3;

     var res4 = str1.concat(a,str2,c,str3,f);

     document.getElementById("res4").innerHTML = res4;

     /////////////////////////////////////////////

}

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = 'test';
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("wrapper").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("wrapper");
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.click();    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
 #but1,#but2,#but3,#but4,#but5,#but6,#but7,#but8,#but9,#but10,#but11,#but12,#but13,#but14,#but15,#but16,#but17,#but18,#but19,#but20,#but21,#but22
 {
  display: none;
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js">
<body>
lorem ipsum text

<label>lorem ipsum text</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a" id="myText1"><br>

lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter b" id="myText2"><br>

lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
lorem ipsum text

<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter c" id="myText3"><br>
lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter d" id="myText4"><br>
lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter e" id="myText5"><br>
lorem ipsum text

lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter f" id="myText6"><br>
lorem ipsum text

<br><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<a href="" id="link" onclick="setupDownloadLink('#wrapper', txt.value)" download="code.txt">Download file</a>

<div id="wrapper">
<p id="col"></p>
<p id="one"></p>
<p id="two"></p>
<p id="three"></p>
<p id="four"></p>
<p id="five"></p>
<p id="six"></p>
<p id="res1"></p>
<button id="but1" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res1')">Copy</button>
<p id="res2"></p>
<button id="but2" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res2')">Copy</button>

<p id="res3"></p>
<button id="but3" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res3')">Copy</button>
<p id="res4"></p>
<button id="but4" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res4')">Copy</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made some adjusts on your JS code, there was some logic errors... also i edited the `<a>` tag and changed it and its function... I think it is working much better now.
 please, take a look.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
function myFunction() {

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 document.getElementById("but1").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but2").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but3").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but4").style.display = "block";


 var a = document.getElementById("myText1").value;

    var b = document.getElementById("myText2").value;

    var c = document.getElementById("myText3").value;

    var d = document.getElementById("myText4").value;

    var e = document.getElementById("myText5").value;

    var f = document.getElementById("myText6").value;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var col = "Variables You Entered:";

  var one = "People you are going to teach:" + a;
  var two = "#1 Result They Really Want:" + b;
  var three = "#2 Result They Really Want:" + c; 
  var four = "#1 Thing They FEAR Most: " + d;
  var five = "#2 Thing They FEAR Most:" + e;
  var six = "Time frame You Can Deliver in:" + f;

  document.getElementById("col").innerHTML = col;

  //var onetext = one.concat(a);

  document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = one;
  document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = two;
  document.getElementById("three").innerHTML = three;
  document.getElementById("four").innerHTML = four;


     var str1 = "I'm going to teach ";

     var str2 = " how to ";

     var str3 = " in ";

     var str4 = " and ";

     var str5 = " without ";

     var str6 = " or ";


     var res1 = str1.concat(a,str2,b);

     document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = res1;

     var res2 = str1.concat(a,str2,b,str3,c);

     document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = res2;

     ////////////////////////////////

     var res3 = str1.concat(a,str2,c);

     document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = res3;

     var res4 = str1.concat(a,str2,c,str3,f);

     document.getElementById("res4").innerHTML = res4;

     /////////////////////////////////////////////

}

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerText;
    //Use replace if you want to remove something, like the word Copy...
    fileNameToSaveAs = fileNameToSaveAs.replace(/Copy/g,"");
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([fileNameToSaveAs], {type:'text/plain'});

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.download = textFileAsBlob;
    downloadLink.click();    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
 #but1,#but2,#but3,#but4,#but5,#but6,#but7,#but8,#but9,#but10,#but11,#but12,#but13,#but14,#but15,#but16,#but17,#but18,#but19,#but20,#but21,#but22
 {
  display: none;
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js">
<body>
lorem ipsum text

<label>lorem ipsum text</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a" id="myText1"><br>

lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter b" id="myText2"><br>

lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
lorem ipsum text

<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter c" id="myText3"><br>
lorem ipsum text
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter d" id="myText4"><br>
lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter e" id="myText5"><br>
lorem ipsum text

lorem ipsum text
<br><input type="text" placeholder="enter f" id="myText6"><br>
lorem ipsum text

<br><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<a href="" id="link" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Download file</a>

<div id="wrapper">
<p id="col"></p>
<p id="one"></p>
<p id="two"></p>
<p id="three"></p>
<p id="four"></p>
<p id="five"></p>
<p id="six"></p>
<p id="res1"></p>
<button id="but1" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res1')">Copy</button>
<p id="res2"></p>
<button id="but2" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res2')">Copy</button>

<p id="res3"></p>
<button id="but3" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res3')">Copy</button>
<p id="res4"></p>
<button id="but4" onclick="copyToClipboard('#res4')">Copy</button>

</div>
```

**EDIT**: to remove the word "Copy", use the replace method (I updated the snippet and commented that part) with the `g` tag to remove all occurences... 
about the no line breaks, for me, there is a line break after every line.. if you want to add more, just append some `<br>` tags and then when will make the download, replace it with `\n\r`

Comment: Thank you so much @calvin. but they all are in one line

Comment: what do you mean with all in one line?

Comment: i mean there is no line break in the downloaded file, and there is word copy also. which is not want in the downloaded file.

Comment: I made an edit, take a look, it is possible the best I can help for now